# "Love" letter number three

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

That was too easy. I solved it during physics, although I did let some of my internet friends take a crack at it, since they seem to enjoy puzzles. You need practice. (Admittedly, so do I.) Here’s a puzzle that you may or may not enjoy, since you like Ted Hughes and I like Sylvia Plath, you like Shakespeare and I like Gabriel Rossetti. It’s some sort of conglomeration of a few of their quotes.

I hate also taken in consideration you statement concerning potatoes, and have concluded that at least you tried to make an effort to write a puzzle and make up for it. Potatoes will remain the love of my life, and I suppose you could take up second place. Take it or leave it.

Here’s your puzzle. It’s not relevant to anything, so I don’t think the answer will be as easy as yours was. Just find the first letter of the titles of the volumes/collections/poems in which the quotes come from for the first “tier” of the puzzle. The keyword should be relatively simple to guess, because I love it, and I italicized the important parts...

*I am dogged in my pursuit of confirming my turpitude, and execrate the Integrated Development Environment, enjoyment that arises as a result of the current days,* my friend Gansey told me. We were walking through a museum, and I was thinking about you because I’d seen this picture of a woman raising her hand to touch something that she could not reach. You’re a wonderful guy, Henry, but sometimes your heart seems to race past all boundaries and out of my reach.

I saw an illustration. *A companion to an illustration in 1881, Can day from darkness ever take flight?* My friend comments, and I look at him, the meaning of his words beyond me, but possibly not beyond you. I wonder if he thinks that I am a receptacle of knowledge into which he can toss whatever quote he’d been thinking of.

*Flies watch no resurrection in the sun.* I replied with a quote of my own, as we exited the museum, and I thought about how much that painting spoke to me, wondering if things like this happened in real life.

After the exchange with Gansey, I went to look for you, although, I didn’t look too hard, I have to admit. I was in a ponderous mood.

*The table-top, made of the same wood that James Potter’s wand is made of, that you smashed had been the broad plank top of my mother's heirloom sideboard- mapped with the scars of my whole life.*

*You have been the last dream of my soul,* Henry, no matter how careless I happen to be... sometimes I feel like I should apologize for being me.

*We got everything you want honey, we know the names*, my friends had told me, and I’d followed them. There’s always something intoxicating about receiving validation from people you don’t see in real life, but, *“You are who you choose to be,”* Ted Hughes told me, and my eyelids drooped shut and I drifted off to sleep.

*He declares there is nothing he can do for this beautiful woman who seems to be alive and dead. He is not a doctor. He can only pray.* Gosh, Henry, there’s no hope for me, I keep making mistakes!

Have fun with the puzzle, honey. I wrapped it up pretty nicely in my nonsensical rambling, which is mostly for your entertainment.

Love, Zipporah

Comment: Stack exchange is so confusing.

Comment: Not as confusing as your letter ;)

Comment: Damn, that very first italicized section is so convoluted... I managed to get all the other ones, but I suspect I can't guess at the keyword until I have all the names.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I feel like although not encoded, it should be relatively simple to guess the keyword. It's been in all the letters.

Comment: Am I supposed to get one letter from each italicized section? For each section, find out the poem/text/song/movie/etc it was taken from, and take the title's first letter, even if it consists of multiple words? What if the title starts with "the"? I am 100% certain of all the quotes except the first one, and taking the titles' first letter, I can't find any word containing them.

Comment: Yes, one letter from each, and always the first letter. You may have gathered hat I'm not the master of trying to subtly incorporate letters into paragraphs and so it's sorta awkward, sorry. No 'the', it's usually negligible, isn't it? It's not exactly and anagram, either. (Sorry I suck at puzzles).

Answer (score 4):

**[INCOMPLETE ANSWER]**

I am kinda stuck so I'll just post what I have so far in hopes of inspiring someone!

---

**Italicized sections:**
In each section we are looking for the first letter of the title of the volume/collection/poem/movie/etc that the quote in (or described by) the section is from.

*I am dogged in my pursuit of confirming my turpitude, and execrate the Integrated Development Environment, enjoyment that arises as a result of the current days*

> I haven't been able to solve this one.
>
>  This is one messed up sentence, if it can even be called that. I've tried Googling for parts of this sentence, including variations by word synonyms, but to no avail.
>
>  On another note, *Integrated Development Environment* has no place in the sentence. Maybe the letter of this section is simply I from IDE? That would however be quite strange as then this would be the only section that is not a quote from something.

*A companion to an illustration in 1881, Can day from darkness ever take flight?*

> [Dante Gabriel Rossetti, Ballads and Sonnets (1881), "**F**ound"](http://www.rossettiarchive.org/docs/2-1881.1stedn.rad.html#A.R.131).
>  First letter: **F**.
>
>  *Note:* actual quote: *"Can day from darkness ever **again** take flight?"*

*Flies watch no resurrection in the sun*

> Sylvia Plath, **N**ovember Graveyard (1956)
>  First letter: **N**.

*The table-top, made of the same wood that James Potter’s wand is made of, that you smashed had been the broad plank top of my mother's heirloom sideboard- mapped with the scars of my whole life.*

> Ted Hughes, The **M**inotaur.
>  First letter: **M**. (Author said to ignore "the"s.)
>
>  *Note:* actual quote:
>  
>  "The mahogany table-top you smashed
>  Had been the broad plank top
>  Of my mother’s heirloom sideboard—
>  Mapped with the scars of my whole life."
>
>  James Potter's (from Harry Potter) wand is made of mahogany.

*We got everything you want honey, we know the names*

> Guns N' Roses, **W**elcome To The Jungle.
>  First letter: **W**.

*You are who you choose to be*

> Ted Hughes, The **I**ron Man. (Again, ignore "the"s.)
>  First letter: **I**.

*We came into the world like brother and brother, and now let's go hand in hand, not one before another*

> William Shakespeare, The **C**omedy of Errors. (Again, ignore "the"s.)
>  First letter: **C**.

---

So that gives us the following letters:

> _ F N M W I C ('_' for unsolved section.)
>
>  I don't know what to make of these.

Comment: Does it always have to be the title of the *written* piece? You may be able to substitute F for B above, if not.

Comment: @question_asker I'm not sure I follow. You're saying there's something else "A companion to an illustration in 1881, Can day from darkness ever take flight?" may be referring to?

Comment: Since you asked, yes, specifically the fact that it might be referring to the illustration to which the line is a companion. (Also, since posting that comment, I realized the "song for Paul Walker" might be hinting at something, which could possibly be an H or an S?). And, of course, the keyword (which I think is obvious what it is, but how it fits into this puzzle is still a mystery to me). Very importantly: I'm not OP, so I could be following red herrings.

Comment: @question_asker I think you're right about the illustration. I'm searching now to find out what illustration it is. Also, the letter says "Just find the first letter of the titles of the volumes/collections/poems in which the quotes come from for the first “tier” of the puzzle." I'm pretty sure finding the keyword from these quotes is just the first step which will hopefully hint us to solving the rest. So Paul Walker and other stuff may very well be part of the second "tier" of the puzzle I guess?

Comment: Yeah, true. The more avenues I try in this one, the more confused I get.

Comment: Ah you said "F" because you had already found it. It's called "Found". http://www.rossettiarchive.org/docs/2-1881.1stedn.rad.html#A.R.131 There seems to be no accompanying illustration though.

Comment: Hey, hey, chill guys. I'm not THAT great of a riddler, even if I wished I was. Zippy's just sort of a weird character. You've gotten most of it right, good for you. I did not anticipate this much ambiguity, I'm sorry.

Comment: Maybe "IDE" should be read as "ide" (as in "ides of March") or be replaced with the name of an IDE such as "Eclipse"?  The latter part could mean something like "glory days"...  The endgame might be finding a 7-word title beginning with those letters.